# make arduino start when a line is broken

Tags: arduino, power, transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwvS5M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi. I'm trying to build an anti-theft project. Where if you break a thin wire connexion, It should power ON the arduino and let it do its thing.

As long as the wire on top is not broken, it should draw nothing from the battery and the whole circuit should be OFF. This is important because I need the battery to last many years as this event will occure very rarely.

*Optional: would be nice if power to arduino shuts down when the line on top is connected back.*

What should I use in the "some magic" box ?

Comment: Without some power, this really isn't feasible.

Comment: Essentially you need something that sleeps at miniscule power and wakes up periodically to send a tiny current through the wire and see if it is still connected.  That something could be an Arduino-like ATmega processor carefully configured **and without the power-wasting rest of the Arduino** or it could be something just for this purpose, which powers up an actual Arduino when the condition is met.  You probably want one of the squat lithium cells or perhaps two AA's, not a 9v battery.

Comment: Yeah -- it's possible to get standby consumption down to the submicroamp range I reckon, which should be good enough for these purposes